# Make VBA execute a binary compiled in Mac

Tags: vba, binary, ocaml, cross-platform, interop

I have a simple tryOCaml.ml as follows:

```
let () = Printf.printf("Hello World\n");
```

Then, under Mac, I complied it to bytecode executable file by `ocamlc -o tryOCaml tryOCaml.ml`. As a result, `./tryOCaml` in a terminal showed well `Hello World`.

I wanted to run this executable under Windows. I copied the file to my virtual machine Windows. Under Command Prompt, I tried `tryOCaml`, it returned `'tryOCaml' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My final goal was actually to run it in VBA, in an Excel file under Windows, I wrote a macro:

```
Sub try()
    Call Shell("C:\Users\SoftTimur\Downloads\tryOCaml")
End Sub
```

It returned an error `Invalid procedure call or argument`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I also wrote an Excel file under Mac with the following macro:

```
Sub try()
    Call Shell("/Users/SoftTimur/ImproveOCaml/tryOCaml")
End Sub
```

However, it returned an error `File not found`.

Could anyone help?

Comment: One wouldn't expect a binary compiled on a Mac, to run on Windows. The executable formats are not compatible. Have you tried installing the OCaml tools on the Windows virtual machine and compiling your very simple OCaml source file there?

Comment: My real project in OCaml is quite big, and I cannot compile it on Windows. Do you know if it is possible to make Shell of VBA work with the binary in Excel for Mac?

Comment: VBA is outside of my realm of expertise, but it does appear VBA will work with Excel for Mac. [This Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac) may be helpful.